# Cant submit form using Ajax, Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have advertisement and message models with forms. Both forms submits using Ajax (**remote => true**).

**Message form submits perfect. It stays in the same page and handles response, but advertisement form does not.** 
Both form,controller and script code is the same. Just changes from *message* to *advertisement*..

**Advertisement form.**

```
<%= form_for(@advertisement, :html => {"data-parsley-validate" => true},remote: true, format: :json) do |f| %>
        ....
         #lot of code here
        ....

<%end%>
```

Advertisement controller:

```
 def create

   @advertisement = Advertisement.new(advertisement_params.merge(service_ids: params[:service_ids]))


      respond_to do |format|
             if @advertisement.save
               format.html { redirect_to @advertisement, notice: 'advertisement was successfully sent.' }
               format.json { render json: @advertisement }
             else
               format.html { render action: 'new' }
               format.json { render json: @advertisement.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
             end
         end
   end
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $("#new_advertisement").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
  alert("ok");
  }).on("ajax:error", function(e, xhr, status, error) {

    alert("Error registration");
  });
});
```

After submit I am redirected to this link:

```
http://localhost:3000/lv/advertisements.json
```

And browser displays all parameters that has been sent:

```
{"id":45,"name":"dsad","subname":"dasd","country_id":1,"region_id":3,"age":18,"height":144,"phone_number":"26266262","weight":42,"description":"das","created_at":"2015-03-04T18:50:23.924+02:00","updated_at":"2015-03-04T18:50:23.924+02:00","in_blacklist":false,"admin_confirmed":false,"vip":false,"identifier":"42179","expiration":"2015-04-29T18:50:23.926+03:00","smsidentifier":null,"highlight":"2015-03-04T18:50:23.926+02:00","recomend":"2015-03-04T18:50:23.927+02:00","vip_highlight":"2015-03-04T18:50:23.927+02:00","vip_recomend":"2015-03-04T18:50:23.927+02:00","prolong":null,"description_ru":"dasdad","work1":"2","work2":"3","work3":"7","work4":"17","email":"dasd66666@dsdsadas.lv","can_add_review":true,"can_show_recomended":true,"paid":false,"token":"","user_id":null}
```

I checked, advertisement is created succesfully, but why this weird redirect happens only for advertisement ? Not messages too ?

Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your problem is the redirecting?

Comment: @RailsOuter, Yes, thats true. Also if ajax success there has to be alert, but there isn't ..

Comment: Try to remove the :format :json, and replace your `form_for` with this:
`<%= form_for(@advertisement,:html => {"data-parsley-validate" => true, :'data-type' => 'json'}, remote: true) do |f| %>`
I have successfully post the data to json.

Comment: @KhoaPham Thanks, but still the same problem..

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds Can you inspect to see if there's anything unusual in your Rails logs? Here is the repo that I just created with two scaffolds for Message and Advertisement: https://github.com/pmkhoa/stackoverflow-submit-ajax They just work.

Comment: @KhoaPham Thanks, I finally found reason. Ajax didn't work because of the image upload from the same form..

Answer (score 1):

I would catch the success and error events with jquery on your script I would try something like this:

```
if @advertisement.save
  format.html { redirect_to @advertisement, notice: 'advertisement was successfully sent.' }
  format.js
else
  format.html { render action: 'new' }
  format.json { render status: :500 } //Set the error right now so you can catch it later on your script
```

Depending on your needs you can also do

```
if @advertisement.save
  format.html { redirect_to @advertisement, notice: 'advertisement was successfully sent.' }
  format.js, alert: "your success message"
else
  format.html { render action: 'new' }
format.json { render nothing: true }, alert: "your error message" // so you don't have to catch any errors on the script
```

And on your script just use jquery to manage AJAX

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "THE URL YOU ARE POSTING TO",
  dataType: "json",
});
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer above. The author found the bug in his form which related to image upload field.